# How to replace all `$` character by `$$` in a txt file

Tags: vim, replace

There are many `$` and `$$` in my txt file, and I want to replace all `$` by `$$`. For example,

```
$x$ is a variable, and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a formula.

$$
x^2 + y^2 = 1
$$
Here is another formula $$ \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$$.
```

I try to do it like this:

`:%s/[^\$]\$[^\$]/\$\$/g`

but which can not work well. So what is the correct command? Thanks very much.

Comment: Please add the desired output.

Comment: Why doesn't it work well?

Comment: In the example, I just need to change the first line to `$$x$$ is a variable, and $$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$ is a formula`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
:%s/\$\$\?/\$\$/g
```

That replaces any occurrence of either `$` or `$$` with `$$` so it does what I think you want with single or double `$`.

It's not clear to me what you expect `$$$` to be changed to. The above will force all runs of `$` to be of even length, so `$$$` will change to `$$$$`. If you only want to change single `$` you can use the slightly more complicated command:

```
:s/\$\?\(\$\+\)/\$\1/g
```

Comment: Hi, rici, thanks very much for your help. It works for my case! By the way, I just want to change single `$`.